# Sharing Data Between Components

Tags: angular, rxjs

If I need to share data between components, for example I can inject a `dataService` with a field named `width`, inputs bound to said field on each component: `[(ngModel)]="dataService.width"`. This works, if I type in component-1 input, the data shows up in component-2's input as I type. My question is why would I need to make `width` Observable and subscribe to it everywhere? It seems to be updating without making it `Observable/EventEmitter`.

Being new to `Angular` I have to be missing something.

Comment: It depends on the relationships between the components, what's your case?

Comment: @bugs parent-child and (siblings all under the same parent). So I'm assuming Observable would need to be used when no relationship ie: a totally clean separate component?

Comment: Parent to Child: simply use an `@Input()`, no event required. Child to parent: use an EventEmitter with an `@Output()`. Everything else (usually): Shared service injected in both components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your example is as simple as displaying the value or binding it to the input you can stick to the non observable solution.

But real world situations are much more complex. Let's say the value in your service changes and you need to:

- invoke a method in your component
- delegate to a method in a service
- emit an `@Output` event
- make an http request

These are the situations where `observables` can really help you out.

As always, it's about choosing the right tool for the job. Sometimes a simple data binding will be enough. Other times you will have to reach for the observable solution.